# Does $C(n)$ grow exponential versus $n$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, exponential-function, carmichael-function

Let $λ(m)=n$ be the [Carmichael Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function) of $m$. For each (even) number $n$, there is a largest number $m$ such that $λ(m)=n$. Let $C(n)$ denote the largest integer $m$ such that $λ(m)=n$. For instance, $C(2)=24$ and $C(4)=240$ since $24$ and $240$ are the largest numbers with Carmichael Function equal to $2$ and $4$ respectively. In these cases, $n$ is really small, and $C(n)$ is rather large compared to $n$. However for other $n$, $C(n)$ and $n$ are about the same size so there is no significant growth rate of $C(n)$ compared to $n$. Suppose this is not the case. So as $n$ gets larger and larger, is it possible that $C(n)$ will grow exponential compared to $n$? If not, what is the **maximum** growth rate of $C(n)$ compared to $n$?

Comment: Hmm, for the special case of $n$ being a power of $2$, the growth of $C(2^k)$ depends on the distribution of Fermat primes, and we don't even know if there are more than $5$ of those ... so this sounds pretty intractable.

Comment: You could calculate a few values of $C(n)$ and then look it up in the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences, oeis.org

Comment: See [OEIS sequence A321712](https://oeis.org/A321712).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function#Small_values), there is a positive constant $c$ such that for sufficiently large $A$, there is $n > A$ with $\lambda(n) < (\ln A)^{c \ln \ln \ln A}$.  That says if $m = \lambda(n)$, $C(m) \ge n > A$.  Note that 
$$m = \lambda(n) < \exp(c (\ln \ln A)(\ln \ln \ln A)) < \exp(c (\ln \ln A)^2)$$
so
$$C(m) > \exp(\exp(\ln(m)^{1/2}/c^{1/2}))$$
This is not quite as good as exponential growth, but I guess it is the best result known (or was at the time of writing).